# Perl script use of gpg vs. CLI gpg?

Tags: linux, perl, gnupg

As part of a perl script, I am downloading some files from a website based on cycle numbers obtained from emails. I use a regexp to find the appropriate cycle number, append that to a url and grab an encrypted file from said url. I then print the encrypted file to a temp file, and use gpg to decrypt that temp file, dumping the output into another location. Clear as mud?

Here's where things get interesting. This is the command that is used to decrypt the temp file:

```
my $cmd = 'cat ~/.gpgkey | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --no-tty --batch --quiet 
          --no-mdc-warning --decrypt $filename >> ~/SAT.SCR';
```

If you'll notice, the command uses a $filename variable. I have separately confirmed that this variable is pointing to the correct file. However, this command yields the following error:

```
gpg: decrypt_message failed: Unknown system error
```

If, however, I run the above command straight from the shell (csh), replacing $filename with the actual file, it works perfectly. We are using gpg 2.0.9.

Does anyone have an idea why the decryption is failing when called from the perl script but not from the shell?

Comment: Post a complete sample program that reproduces the error and we'll be better able to help you. :)

Comment: How are you actually executing `$cmd`? With `system($cmd)`? Do the tildes get expanded at any point (my guess is they don't, but I don't have much experience with Csh ... and [neither should you](http://www.perl.com/doc/FMTEYEWTK/versus/csh.whynot))?

Comment: My experience with csh since becoming aware of the debate is not by choice. I am in the process of getting everything to work properly in bash; my school's ERP is rather particular.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl doesn't interpolate variables in strings with single quotes. Try using a string with double quotes:

```
my $cmd = "cat ~/.gpgkey | gpg --passphrase-fd 0 --no-tty --batch --quiet 
      --no-mdc-warning --decrypt $filename >> ~/SAT.SCR";
system($cmd);
```

See [Quote and Quote-like Operators in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) for more information.